# Не воспринимается код на VPS

Tags: php, vps

Снял вчера VPS. Нагуглил мануалы базовых настроек, вроде всё настроил.
Создал в /var/www/ тестовую папку phpinfo, в ней создал index.php
Но беда, открываю в браузере [http://мойдомен/phpinfo](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD/phpinfo), вместо инфы, в браузере открывается просто не скомпилированный мой код из index.php
В чём может быть проблема? Подозреваю, что я упустил что-то очень важное и очевидное.

ОС Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

PHP5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После двух вечеров порнографии с сервером, я всё таки нашёл проблему. Как и предполагал я упустил важное и очевидное. Я проштудировал десятки блогов и статей на эту тему, но нигде не говорится про настройку конфигурации apache2. В итоге проблему решил созданный файл в папке с конфигами apache2. Прописал там три строчки: первая - имя сервер, вторая - на разрешение использование php-скриптов (в чем и заключалась проблема), и третья - кодировка по умолчанию UTF-8. После это php заработал, как родной.

Всем кто пытался помочь, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

1. Какая панель управления на VPS
2. Домен прикрепили, DNS настроены? Вообще домен сначала заглушку на главной странице должен показывать.
3. Судя по описанию похоже что этому юзеру просто не разрешили использовать PHP

Comment: 1. Настраивал через консоль PuTTY
2. Домен прикреплён, по домену выходит главная страница Убунту-Апач.
3. Да, вовремя настройки, создал нового юзера. Вроде все права root-юзера ему передал. Можно, пожалуйста, по этому пункту по подробнее.

Comment: Можно просто задать владельца/группу: `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`

Comment: Я вам тут точно не смогу подсказать, мало данных, может там вообще веб-сервер не стоит на сервере не apache, ни nginx. В конфигах вебсервера для каждого хоста указываются нужные настройки

Answer (score 2):

Возможно не установлен или не подключен к веб-серверу интерпретатор PHP

Comment: А как это можно проверить, наверняка?

Comment: Выполните в консоли сервера php  -v

Comment: Должна появиться информация об интерпретаторе и его версии. Установить модуль для Apache и включить его можно так: Модуль для Apache
PHP в виде модуля для Apache можно установить так:
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
Включить модуль PHP 5 в Apache можно выполнив:
sudo a2enmod php5

Comment: да, версия отображается и отображалась, А вот код пхп работать не хочет -=((